How can I display records for the last 30 days and sort them by the number of views?
To count the number of views for each element, I use the Entry count plugin (https://plugins.craftcms.com/entry-count ). I want to display the entries from the 'news' section for the last month and sort them by the number of views. Here's what I wrote:
{% set dateFrom = now|date_modify('-1 month')|atom %}
{% set dateTo = now|atom %}

{% set entries = craft.entries().section('news').postDate(['and', ">= #{dateFrom}", "< #{dateTo}"]).all() %}

{% for element in entries %}
    {{element}}
{% endfor %}

My code only outputs entries for the month. I can't figure out how to add sorting by number of views to my query. Please help me figure it out. Thank you in advance
